# How to change KDE Plasma scrollbar width?

Tags: plasma-5, scrollbar

How can I change the scrollbar width in KDE Plasma 5.9.4 on Ubuntu 17.04?

The `Application Style` dialog box no longer contains this setting.

Answer (score 1):

In KUbuntu 20.04 I found by changing some numbers in: `/usr/share/themes/Breeze/gtk-3.0`

Towards the end, in my case lines starting at line 38456, fixed my problem.

```
scrollbar trough {
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    min-width: 20px;
}
```

and

```
scrollbar:hover trough {
    background-color: mix(@theme_unfocused_bg_color,@theme_unfocused_fg_color,0.7);
    min-width: 18px;
}
scrollbar:hover slider {
    min-width: 18px;
}
```

Comment: It would be wiser to add these fixes to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` rather than altering main theme `gtk.css` directly. One more point: these fixes alter only vertical scrollbar. To change the horizontal one `scrollbar.horizontal trough` and `scrollbar.horizontal slider` selectors should be used also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about 17.04, but in 18.04 you can select the Oxygen style, which has a setting for the scrollbar width. The default Breeze does not.

For gtk applications I created my own theme in ~/.themes based on an existing one in /usr/share/themes and modified gtk.css to make the scrollbar larger. This is easier with gtk-3.20 than with previous versions, you just have to increase some min-width in the Scrollbars section, and optionally the border-radius. In 3.18 and earlier you have to increase the stretch dimensions for many elements, in the same file.

Still, I wish developers would just use at least 20 pixels for a scrollbar by default, it's not too much out of 1920 pixels and these are well spent pixels...